# Python Web Scraping: Ahref link and articles not showing up in source code

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to find the articles via requests for url = "https://corporate.dow.com/en-us/news.html" but when I access the source code, the press release articles do not show up.

I tried using Selenium, but even then the ahref links or article titles don't show up. The source code ends up looking like: 
[screen shot of relevant part of source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrCpW.png)

Comment: this page uses JavaScript to add content. `requests` and `BeautifuSoup` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) ot control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: source code shows original code from server - before browser runs JavaScript. You have to use `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox to see code with changes.

Comment: where is your code? Did you get error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 2):

This page uses JavaScript to add items so you have to use `Selenium`.

I don't know what problem you had with Selenium because you didn't show code and any error message (two more imporatant elements in question) but I have no problem to get titles and url

```
import selenium.webdriver

url = 'https://corporate.dow.com/en-us/news.html'
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="results__list"]/li')
for item in all_items:
    print(item.find_element_by_xpath('.//h3').text)
    print(item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href'))
    print('---')
```

Part of result:

```
Dow hosts tree planting event in Louisiana to officially kick off reforestation commitment with Restore the Earth Foundation
https://corporate.dow.com/en-us/news/press-releases/dow-tree-planting-louisiana-restore-the-earth-foundation.html
---
Dow wins four prestigious 2019 R&D 100 Awards from R&D World Magazine
https://corporate.dow.com/en-us/news/press-releases/dow-wins-four-prestigious-2019-r-d-100-awards-from-r-d-world-mag.html
---
Dow Leaders Achieve Top Honors on OUTstanding’s 2019 Leading LGBT+ Professionals Lists
https://corporate.dow.com/en-us/news/press-releases/dow-leaders-achieve-top-honors-on-outstandings-2019-leading-lgbt.html
---
Dow Reports Third Quarter 2019 Results
https://corporate.dow.com/en-us/news/press-releases/dow-reports-third-quarter-2019-results.html
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. When trying the code, I got popup message (\with Accept / Deny buttons). How to bypass the alert?

Comment: find button `Accept` and `.click()` it.

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_id('cookie-continue').click()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry as I am beginner. Now the alert is off but I ddin't get the results .. I have added `import time` and add `time.sleep(5)` so as to get the results. Is there another way to do that without using waiting methods?

Comment: `Selenium` has [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) methods but I never remeber syntax and usually I use `time.sleep` instead

Comment: so you mean it is must to use waits methods. Is there a way that lets the code continue only if the page fully loaded?

Comment: some elements can be added after page is fully loaded - and selenium has `wait` methods for this.

Comment: Yes I have read about implicit and explicit approaches. But what I mean is the page in general (not specific elements)

Comment: browser can see that HTML sended from server is fully loaded but it doesn't mean it is fully rendered. There is no method to answer if JavaScript added all elements to page - it can use AJAX to add elements with delay or when you scroll page. Many pages uses "lazy loading" for images - to load them only when scroll.

Comment: BTW: SEO tutorials say that people may leave page if it loads longer then 2-3 seconds so authors try to create pages which load fast - ie.they skip elements which they don't have to show at once.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to search this pattern in developer tools `//ul[@class="results__list"]/li` .. I need to search the h3 within this pattern

Comment: in `DevTools` in `Firefox` in `Inspect` you can uses CSS selectors - `.results__list li h3` - when you press `Enter` then it shows first matching element, when you press `Enter` again then it shows next element, etc.

Comment: in `DevTools` in `Chrome` in `Elements` you can press `Ctrl+F` to show place for `xpath`. Firefox can't uses `xpath` directly: [How do I search with XPath in Firefox Quantum 65?](https://superuser.com/questions/1407080/how-do-i-search-with-xpath-in-firefox-quantum-65)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can get all the titles and their links using requests exhausting load more button. Try using chrome dev tools to find the url that I've used within the below script.

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = 'https://corporate.dow.com/.corporate-search.servlet.json/?x1=ContentType;q1=News;page={};sp_s=StartDate;x20=ContentSubTypeMaster;q20=Olympics%20News%7CInvestor%7CCompany%7CBusiness%7CAll'
base = 'https://corporate.dow.com/'
page = 1

while True:
    res = requests.get(url.format(page))
    if not res.json()['resultsets'][0]['results']:break
    for item in res.json()['resultsets']:
        for elem in item['results']:
            title = elem['ContentTitle']
            link = urljoin(base,elem['RelativeURL'])
            print(f"{'Title: '}{title}\n{'Link: '}{link}\n")
    page+=1
```

Output you may have are like:

```
Title: Dow hosts tree planting event in Louisiana to officially kick off reforestation commitment with Restore the Earth Foundation
Link: https://corporate.dow.com/en-us/news/press-releases/dow-tree-planting-louisiana-restore-the-earth-foundation.html

Title: Dow wins four prestigious 2019 R&D 100 Awards from R&D World Magazine
Link: https://corporate.dow.com/en-us/news/press-releases/dow-wins-four-prestigious-2019-r-d-100-awards-from-r-d-world-mag.html

Title: Dow Leaders Achieve Top Honors on OUTstanding’s 2019 Leading LGBT+ Professionals Lists
Link: https://corporate.dow.com/en-us/news/press-releases/dow-leaders-achieve-top-honors-on-outstandings-2019-leading-lgbt.html
```

Comment: Awesome. How to export the results to text file.. as I am newbie to python? .. When navigate to the url in the code, I got http status 400 (bad request). Any idea?

Comment: You get 400 status navigating to that url only because there is a string format in that url. Try [this](https://corporate.dow.com/.corporate-search.servlet.json/?x1=ContentType;q1=News;page=1;sp_s=StartDate;x20=ContentSubTypeMaster;q20=Olympics%20News%7CInvestor%7CCompany%7CBusiness%7CAll) instead.

Comment: Great. But why when testing your code it shows results perfectly .. although the url is invalid. I am little confused

Comment: You failed to notice this portion within the url `page={}` which is handled by this `url.format(page)`.

Comment: I have noticed it in fact but can't get how it is handled till yet. Can you please explain this point?

Comment: Give [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/) a go to get the clarity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this wonderful link. I now got it well. Can you please guide me how to export the results to text file?

Comment: I could figure it out using this line `f = open('Output.txt', 'w')` after `page = 1' Then using `print(f"{'Title: '}{title}\n{'Link: '}{link}\n", file=f)`

Comment: One last point (sorry for all these questions): how did you get the link that has the JSON information ..Is that by inspecting the base url or what?